# JQuery - Make icons bigger when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, jquery-hover

I have a navbar with icons and under each of them some text(like home, contacts, ecc..). I would like that if I go over the text the icons became bigger. For now I can do it only if the mouse go over the icon.

Here's my navbar:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="img/ico_nav/hamburger.jpg" class="img-circle noinmobile icons" alt="Menù" width="50" height="50" style=" margin-bottom:15px">
                                <p class="navtext">HOME</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#storia">
                                <img src="img/ico_nav/storia.jpg" class="img-circle noinmobile icons" alt="Menù" width="50" height="50" style=" margin-bottom:15px">
                                <p class="navtext">STORIA</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#menù">
                                <img src="img/ico_nav/hamburger.jpg" class="img-circle noinmobile icons" alt="Menù" width="50" height="50" style=" margin-bottom:15px">
                                <p class="navtext">MENÙ</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#gallery">
                                <img src="img/ico_nav/gallery.jpg" class="img-circle noinmobile icons" alt="Menù" width="50" height="50" style=" margin-bottom:15px">
                                <p class="navtext">GALLERY</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#contatti">
                                <img src="img/ico_nav/contatti.jpg" class="img-circle noinmobile icons" alt="Menù" width="50" height="50" style=" margin-bottom:15px">
                                <p class="navtext">CONTATTI</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

And here's the script:

```
function makeBigger() {
        $(this).css({height: '+=10%', width: '+=10%'});
    }
    function returnToOriginalSize() {
        $(this).css({height: "", width: ""});
    } 
    $(function(){
        $('.icons').hover(makeBigger, returnToOriginalSize);
    }
```

As it is now the icons become bigger when hovered, but I want that they become bigger also if the text under the icon is hovered. How can I do it? I tried but unfortunately I couldn't figured out how to do it.

I hope I explained myself!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need javascript for this. You can use simple CSS transitions. Something like:

```
.navbar-nav li img {
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.navbar-nav li:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

If you don't want the transition you can remove the `transition` line. You can also use `width` and `height` instead of `transform` for some way back (in browser time) browser support.